# Testing Client-Side Code w/o Introducing Brittleness

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, bdd

I'm finding it tough to test my client-side code without testing implementation details.

For example, lets say you are testing a login form that displays client-side validation errors and does not submit unless the email and password are present and correctly formatted.

You could write a test independent of classnames, etc. to check if the form did not submit (e.g. no POST request was sent) but if I want to check for specific errors I need to either a) rely on specific error messages or b) specific class names which are both liable to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal should be to push as much logic as you can away from the UI surface into classes or methods that you can unit test independently of the UI surface.

```
function IsValidEmailAddress(string address)
{
    // return true if email address is valid
}
```

The classes or methods so created can be tested with go/no go conditions, so that you don't have to search for an error message.  This is as true of client-side code as it is of server-side code.

Comment: So basically if I'm using a library that handles client-side validation I should not be writing any tests for client-side validation of forms since there are tests already?

Comment: Also in this case would it still be a good idea to test that, for example, no request is made when the form is invalid? For example to make sure the XHR request logic is valid on an SPA application.

Comment: Your question 1: sounds reasonable.

Comment: Your question 2: presumably you are also validating server-side.

Comment: Yes, validating server code. I'm more referring to testing to make sure that the code is, for example, preventing the default form action and either sending or not sending an XHR request based on form validity.

Comment: You can test that once, by hand.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a good general rule of thumb when to automated test something like that vs. when to write a test? What logic did you use to figure out why an automated test isn't necessary? I'm just thinking if I was part of an organization, how would I ensure no one messes it up in the future?

Comment: If it's part of the UI surface, assume that you can't unit test it.  That's why you push as much logic as you can away from the UI surface.

Comment: I see, so logic that can't be pushed server-side shouldn't really be tested? What about when apps are client-side JS logic heavy?

Comment: I assume you have unit tests in the client.  The UI logic doesn't have to be pushed into the server, just far enough away in the client so that you can unit test it.